# Google Chrome freezes and hangs the computer, keyboard mouse, Alt+Ctrl+Del is dead slow?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, freeze

Many time while surfing internet Google Chrome freezes and hangs the computer, keyboard mouse, Alt+Ctrl+Del is dead slow?

The only solution is to reboot the PC. is there any solution?

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium and Google Chrome version is up to date. Cureently it's `14.0.835.163 m`

Comment: Both on same machine?, same type sites?, connection on/off-ing?

Comment: Use Tools > Clear Browsing Data, clean out your cache. Restart Chrome.

Comment: Seems to be unsolved in version 23.0.1271.97. Chrome sometimes hangs my computer for 15 seconds (including mouse pointer), then everything goes back to normal. I have not many plugins but I guess Java, Flash or something similar is the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Typically when ctrl-alt-del responds slowly it means your hard drive is thrashing.

Start by monitoring Chrome by keeping Task Manager open (set it to Always On Top from the menu). If you aren't familiar with Task Manager, you can start it by right-clicking an empty area of the taskbar or hitting ctrl-alt-del. With Task Manager running, try to reproduce whatever is causing the performance degradation. On the processes tab, you'll probably see the memory usage for a process start to skyrocket. That will identify the culprit.

Since Chrome runs a separate process per tab, there is either one offending web page doing this, or (I'd say more likely), a plugin is responsible.

If there's no rhyme nor reason to this slowdown, try disabling some plugins and browsing foe a couple of days. You might be able to narrow it down that way.

Comment: I have the same problem, but with Ubuntu Maverick 10.10. In my case, it seems to be triggered by opening many tabs at once - I normally have lots of tabs open already; opening half a dozen sites virtually simultaneously is likely to drag down the responsiveness, until the video display (X) locks up hard. System still works if you get in over the network (with SSH for instance) but X is unusable. I'll try the suggestion you made; thanks!